# How do i assign a variable to a eval / exec value?

Tags: python, variables, exec, eval

is it possible to assign a variable to a exec / eval value?
this is what i tried

```py
def execute ():
    run_wn = tk.Tk() 
    des1 = tk.Label(run_wn, text = "------------------------------").pack()
    run_value = exec(cmd.get("1.0", "end"))
    value = tk.Label(run_wn, text = run_value)
    des2 = tk.Label(run_wn, text = "------------------------------").pack()
    run_wn.mainloop
bt = tk.Button(wn, text = "run", command = execute).pack()
```

the cmd is a text box..
when i execute this code then it does not return anything in the run screen.
it prints it
is there any way you can asign a value to a exec / eval value and and use it as text in a Label??

this is just a experimental project..

help will be very appreciated!!

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) takes two other positional arguments, dictionaries for globals and locals, so you could exec like this to capture results in a dict:

```py
In [1]: ns = {}
In [2]: exec("p = 1 + 2", globals(), ns)

In [3]: ns
Out[3]: {'p': 3}
```

Exec'ing untrusted code is dangerous. Don't do it if you're mixing user input into the commands unless you really know what you're doing.